# ChipTune music Program?

Tags: music

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04
I create music from time to time and I'm looking for a good
chiptune program, be it a tracker or some other type of composition
program.
Is there any program that anybody could point out?

Cheers!
Arni Geir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in no way my area of expertise, but from what I have seen [this is the most up to date guide](https://www.coconauts.net/blog/2015/02/02/creating-chiptune-style-music-with-ubuntu/) (it is FAR too much to cover here),but, it uses many things like wine and KX repos. Although the guide is well written and even has some videos.

[image]

If you understand the kind of programs you are using ( I did not) and want to get running right away [try this one](http://www.warmplace.ru/soft/sunvox/).

```
wget www.warmplace.ru/soft/sunvox/sunvox-1.9.zip
```

Find `sunvox-1.9.zip` in your home folder extract it and click the right version you need.

[image]

You mention trackers and I [see milky tracker](http://milkytracker.org/) getting a lot of love it is based on Fast Tracker 2

For 32 bit

```
wget cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/milkytracker/milkytracker_0.90.85+dfsg-2.2_i386.deb
```

For 64bit

```
wget cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/milkytracker/milkytracker_0.90.85+dfsg-2.2_amd64.deb
```

Or manually [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/milkytracker)

There debs so use your preferred install method or just click them.

[image]

To round it out you can see [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/making-8bit-music-introduction-free-chiptune-music-trackers/) for more Linux chip tune programs.

Comment: Please see my update, and accept the answer with the tick on the left if this is good for you